# Time-Limit for shell script in AIX

Tags: linux, aix

I want to run a shell script with time limit of 50s.Below work fine in linux.

```
  timeout 50s sudo sh my-script.sh
```

But i have AIX server where i want to run above script with time limit of 50 seconds.So i run same command in AIX but it gives me

```
     timeout command not found
```

Is there similar timeout command in AIX ?

Answer (score 5):

Probably you were using timeout from GNU coreutils. You can install that from AIX Toolbox for Linux, or a third party source, or compile it yourself.

Or, Perl can [schedule a SIGALRM](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html). Several CPAN modules have examples of timeouts, and signal handling in general. Perl should be a bit more portable, may be useful if this is not the only platform difference that annoys you.